# Whats the golang's `stream.Send()` equivalent in python grpc clients in bidirectional stream?

Tags: python-3.x, grpc, grpc-python

Lets say below is the proto for bi-directional stream

```
service RouteGuide {
  // A Bidirectional streaming RPC.
  //
  // Accepts a stream of RouteNotes sent while a route is being traversed,
  // while receiving other RouteNotes (e.g. from other users).
  rpc RouteChat(stream RouteNote) returns (stream RouteNote) {}
}
```

Go defines an interface to send & rec messages inside a bidirectional stream from server to client & vice-versa : [go interface](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/examples/route_guide/routeguide/route_guide_grpc.pb.go#L164). But I couldn't find the same in Python, to send the response inside the stream without making an additional `RouteChat` call.

Also the example provided doesnt talk about sending a request back from [client](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.54.0/examples/python/route_guide/route_guide_client.py#L98)

How can we send the request back to server from client from python grpc clients with in the same stream?

```
def generate_messages():
    messages = [
        make_route_note("First message", 0, 0),
        make_route_note("Second message", 0, 1),
        make_route_note("Third message", 1, 0),
        make_route_note("Fourth message", 0, 0),
        make_route_note("Fifth message", 1, 0),
    ]
    for msg in messages:
        print("Sending %s at %s" % (msg.message, msg.location))
        yield msg


def guide_route_chat(stub):
    responses = stub.RouteChat(generate_messages())
    for response in responses:
        print("Received message %s at %s" % (response.message, response.location))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sync stack (i.e. not asyncio), there is no API like this. Instead, you're expected to pass in an iterator of your outgoing requests. See [this previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55029342/handling-async-streaming-request-in-grpc-python/55032710#55032710) for an example of that.

The asyncio API however *does* have a [`write`/`read` API](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc_asyncio.html#grpc.aio.StreamUnaryCall.write) that is very similar to Go's.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out by customizing the generator. It worked for me. Not tried asyncio yet. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the same stream object to send and receive messages in a bidirectional gRPC. To send a message back to the server from the client, you can simply call the `stream.write()` method on the stream object with the message you want to send.

You can change this function of yours to be this way:

```
def guide_route_chat(stub):
    stream = stub.RouteChat(generate_messages())
    for response in stream:
        print("Received message %s at %s" % (response.message, response.location))
        # Send a message back to the server
        request = RouteNote()
        request.message = "Sending message back to server."
        request.location.latitude = 37.7749
        request.location.longitude = -122.4194
        stream.write(request)
```

It is important to keep in mind that the stream needs to be in active state for you to be able to send messages back. You can check this via `stream.isactive()`

Comment: I didn't find `write()`  method. Got the error `Failed to connect gRPC, error: '_MultiThreadedRendezvous' object has no attribute 'write'`